# Unable to install Actuator agent on volttron 3.5

Tags: python, agent, volttron

```
volttron.platform.packaging ERROR: must be type, not classobj
```

I have started the virtual environment and then volttron using`source env/bin/activate` and `volttron -vv -l volttron.log --developer-mode&` .

---

I'm unable to install any agent and getting the same error everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you run VOLTTRON in the background you must redirect stderr and stdout to /dev/null. We use libraries that write to stdout (much to our chagrin) and if you disown the process and close the terminal this will cause problems when you try to install an agent.

Shut down VOLTTRON and restart it with this (I'm not sure you even need the --developer-mode switch).

```
volttron -vv -l volttron.log --developer-mode > /dev/null 2>&1&
```

Comment: status: error: 'gevent._event.AsyncResult' object has no attribute 'ident' .. Now getting this error if i check `volttrol-ctl status`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the dependent pip libraries incompatibility.

In setup.py, change the versions to

```
`'gevent==1.1.2',`
`'monotonic==1.2',`
'pymodbus==1.2.0',
'setuptools==27.2.0',
'simplejson==3.8.2',
'Smap==2.0.24c780d',
'wheel==0.30.0a0',
```

and in the requirements.txt, change the versions to

```
pytz==2016.6.1
python-dateutil==2.5.3
requests==2.11.1
psutil==4.3.1
ply==3.9
```

This had resolved the issue for us.